# (node:4468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was following a tutorial on modlog channel but i keep getting this error.

`(node:4468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined`

Here is the code

```
client.on('messageDelete', async (client, message) => {
    if (message.partial) await message.fetch();

    let modlog = db.get(`moderation.${message.guild.id}.modlog`);
    if (!modlog) return;

    if (message.channel.id === modlog.channel) return;

    let toggle = modlog.toggle;
    if (!toggle || toggle == null || toggle == false) return;

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Message Deleted")
    .setDescription(`Message deleted in <#${message.channel.id}> by **${message.author.tag}** \n> ${message.content}`)

    return message.guild.channels.cache.get(modlog.channel).send(embed);
})
```

Comment: as far as I can see `messageDelete` event passes a single argument to the callback, `message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Client#messageDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageDelete) event gives you only the [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) as the first argument. The second argument is undefined.

---

```js
client.on("messageDelete", async (message) => {
    if (message.partial) await message.fetch();

    let modlog = db.get(`moderation.${message.guild.id}.modlog`);
    if (!modlog) return;

    if (message.channel.id === modlog.channel) return;

    let toggle = modlog.toggle;
    if (!toggle || toggle == null || toggle == false) return;

    const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle("Message Deleted").setDescription(`Message deleted in <#${message.channel.id}> by **${message.author.tag}** \n> ${message.content}`);

    return message.guild.channels.cache.get(modlog.channel).send(embed);
});
```